# Inkscape ungroup everything from windows command line

Tags: windows, powershell, svg, cmd, inkscape

I converted a bunch of PDFs into individual SVGs for editing. The SVGs are named as the page numbers, so I have a whole folder of 001.svg, 002.svg ... and the problem is they all the objects in each SVG are grouped together and I have ungroup everything before I can edit the pages which takes a few minutes on each page.

Would save some time if I could ungroup all the pages from the command line first. I've looked at the inkscape command line options and maybe this is actually a windows command prompt or powershell question too because I'm not sure how to loop through files incrementally in either of those

I saw some question here for ungrouping from the command line with

`inkscape --actions "select-all:groups; SelectionUnGroup; export-filename: output.svg; export-plain-svg; export-do;" intput.svg`

But even trying that one individual files nothing happens, I did replace inkscape with the full path

Anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information.

Comment: @Compo ah that is useful thanks

Comment: @KJ yep that's where I'm at now still trying to get the individual inkscape command working.  I've been trying `"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --without-gui --verb EditSelectAll --verb SelectionUnGroup --verb FileSave --verb FileQuit "101.svg` for example, and it hangs for a bit but the file is left unmodified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I believe I have solved it. For some reason I don't think it's possible to do this using the "without-gui" flag which is unfortunate. But this is what I ended up using (still takes a few minutes per file, but doesn't require any work on my part"

I'm using Inkscape 0.92 for reference (I believe this would not work in later versions)

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("%~dp0*.svg") do (
echo %%i
    "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" -f "%%i" --verb EditSelectAll --verb
     SelectionUnGroup --verb FileSave --verb FileQuit
)
```

Comment: Yes, this will not work in Inskcape 1.2.2, do not use this - also, you can just use the DeepUngroup extension directly from the command line. No need for involving Inkscape itself.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an easier way by using the 'deep ungroup' Python script from the command line.

Unfortunately, I can only give you the syntax for Linux, so you need to adjust the paths and the '>' (which means 'output into the following file') to your Windows paths and PowerShell syntax.

With default extension settings, it works like so:

```
python3 /usr/share/inkscape/extensions/ungroup_deep.py groups.svg > ungrouped.svg
```

Comment: With snap package the path will look like this `/snap/inkscape/10408/share/inkscape/extensions/ungroup_deep.py`